# Libgdx map changing

Tags: java, libgdx

Im making an rpg game for a FSE project in my computer science class, and I need to change the map in my game. The only problem is that I can change the map by loading in a new map, however for some reason libgdx still remembers the box2d hitboxes from the previous map. I call the method change map after the 1st level has been completed. I don't get an error though

I have tried multiple methods such as dispose and trying to make the new map in different parts of the class

```
 public void ChangeMap(){
    map.dispose();
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("Assets/Maps/World map1.tmx"); //load the new map
    renderer.setMap(map);
    worldcreator = new WorldCreator(world, map);


}
```

Comment: I am not sure if understand your problem correct, but you`re saying that you still see the old map on screen? (Or a mixture of old and new map?) You might want to add the part that renders / draws the map to your question.

Comment: The box2d bodies don't remove if you call map.dispose or change the map. You must remove the bodies from the world with `world.destroyBody(Body body)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks I figured it out, By adding all the bodies to an ArrayList I could then remove them using world.distroyBody, this actually worked